# fallacy for shifting among multiple premises in argument without defending any

Tags: fallacies

**Has any name been assigned for a class of informal fallacy (or cognitive bias) in which someone shifts in dialog between use of various premises to support an argument, without ever allowing any to be adequately examined?**

For example, consider the following hypothetical exchange:

> **Speaker A:** Hypothesis ***H*** is supported by premises ***P1*** and ***P2***, either of which would be sufficient independently.
> **Speaker B:** Support for ***P1*** is rather weak at best.
> **Speaker A:** ***H*** is still supported by ***P2***.
> **Speaker B:** Have you considered common objections to ***P2***?
> **Speaker A:** No, but they would be irrelevant, because no one ever refuted ***P1***.

(Also, is any source available giving a recommendation for how to confront use of this fallacy for an audience or speaker who may not otherwise recognize it?)

Comment: [Gish gallop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gish_gallop):"a rhetorical technique in which a debater attempts to overwhelm an opponent by excessive number of arguments, without regard for the accuracy or strength of those arguments".

Comment: @Conifold: I think the Gish gallop is different, because it is a confusing monologue, rather than a shifty dialog.

Comment: The form of delivery makes no difference to the substance of the tactic. And Gish gallop is used in both debate formats.

Comment: @Conifold: The term may represent, as you say, situations both of monologue and dialog, but it also emphasizes specifically the large volume of information and the short span of time. For such reasons, I am still doubting the applicability to the kind of scenario under discussion, which relates to a tendency retreat to a new issue, of which there may be only a few in total, without acknowledging how it may have been weakened by previous objections.

Comment: Here is something about fallacies, it's a game of loose associations. They do not have precise definitions, only vague descriptions, often overlapping and with different sources drawing lines in different places. There are no names for every little variant people come up with either. There is not even a cogent description of what "fallacy" means, the original meaning of "mistake in reasoning" does not fit many named "fallacies", where there is no reasoning intended. This area is a wrong place to look for precision.

Comment: @Conifold: I understand. It would be interesting to know of any term used  for a scenario that more narrowly describes the one given,  compared to Gish gallup.

Comment: I suggest that this problem is the Fallacy of Four Terms. Definitions and word usage slide around as necessary to fit the intended goal. The proponent calls effectively upon five terms, or six, or whatever number is needed to win. Also known as Throwing a Lot of Mud at the Wall to See if Any of it Sticks.

Comment: @MarkAndrews: Four Terms is a formal fallacy, which I think makes it different from the scenario under discussion, which is a dialectical issue. "Throwing Mud" may be a good match in some ways, though the common form seems to be not to defend a conclusion, but rather to select some particular action as a solution to a problem.